# Use Model collection as data-type in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

**Background**:

This is for a product database prototype, each product can have multiple related products, and each relationship has a type, e.g. 'Accessory', 'Spare Part', 'Related to', 'Similar to', etc.

**Technology**

We are using sequelize js on node to define the model.

**Model Snippet:**

```
sequelize.define('Product', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, comment: 'product name'}
  ...
});

sequelize.define('ProductRelationType', {
   id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
   name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, comment: 'relationship type description' }
});

sequelize.sync({force: false}).then( function() {
   ...
});
```

**Question**

Is it possible to use models themselves as datatypes in Sequelize, to establish a collection in another table, for example:

```
sequelize.define('ProductRelation', {
   id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
   relatedProduct: { type: Product } //reference to product model
});
```

and followed by:

```
Product.hasMany(ProductRelation, { as: 'relatedProducts' });
ProductRelation.hasOne(ProductRelationType, { as: 'RelationType' } );
```

alternatively, exclude the ProductRelation table definition, and use:

```
db.Product.hasMany(db.Product, { through: 'RelatedProduct' } );
db.RelatedProduct.hasMany(db.Product, { through: 'RelatedProduct' } );
```

**Note: These are concept examples, they do not work.**

Any suggestions, or alternative modeling approaches are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It appears, what you want is simply establishing an n:m relationship from `Product` to `Product`.

The only way to get there is by establishing a link- (or "through-") table. You can either do it manually or let `Sequelize` do it automatically using [belongsToMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/):

```
var RelatedProducts = sequelize.define('RelatedProducts', {
    // other columns here
});

Product.belongsToMany(Product, { through: RelatedProducts, foreignKey: 'relatedProductId' });
Product.belongsToMany(Product, { through: RelatedProducts });
```